# Python: convert 1-D array (with equal area coordinate system) to a 2-D array (with Geographic Coordinate Reference System)

Tags: python, projection, coordinate-systems

I have a 1-D array of data (e.g. Precipitation [precip]). Also, I have 1D latitude (min -90 deg., max +90 deg.) and 1D longitude (min 0, max 360 deg.) arrays representing the coordinates of this data. The coordinate system is "**equal area**". It is a global dataset.

My question is how can I convert this 1-D array to a 2-D array with Geographic Coordinate Reference System (i.e. equally spaced grid, both parallels, and meridians) with a spatial resolution of 1 by 1 degree, so that I would have a 180*360 array (preferably, using pyproj / xarray)?

Thanks!

The following is the information of the dataset:

xarray.Dataset

Dimensions:             (eqcell: 41252)

Dimensions without coordinates: eqcell

Data variables:

```
lat                (eqcell) float32 dask.array chunksize=(41252,), meta=np.ndarray

lon                (eqcell) float32 dask.array chunksize=(41252,), meta=np.ndarray

precip              (eqcell) float32 dask.array chunksize=(41252,), meta=np.ndarray
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). Here's the example from the documentation:

---

Suppose we want to interpolate the 2-D function

```
>>> def func(x, y):
...     return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2
```

on a grid in [0, 1]x[0, 1]

```
>>> grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
```

but we only know its values at 1000 data points:

```
>>> points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
>>> values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])
```

This can be done with griddata – below we try out all of the interpolation methods:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import griddata
>>> grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
>>> grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
>>> grid_z2 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

One can see that the exact result is reproduced by all of the methods to some degree, but for this smooth function the piecewise cubic interpolant gives the best results:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.subplot(221)
>>> plt.imshow(func(grid_x, grid_y).T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
>>> plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'k.', ms=1)
>>> plt.title('Original')
>>> plt.subplot(222)
>>> plt.imshow(grid_z0.T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
>>> plt.title('Nearest')
>>> plt.subplot(223)
>>> plt.imshow(grid_z1.T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
>>> plt.title('Linear')
>>> plt.subplot(224)
>>> plt.imshow(grid_z2.T, extent=(0,1,0,1), origin='lower')
>>> plt.title('Cubic')
>>> plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 6)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: plot]
<sub>(source: [scipy.org](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/_images/scipy-interpolate-griddata-1.png))</sub>

Comment: @Abedeh - As far as I can tell, your problem exactly mirrors the example from the docs as follows: `points[:,0]` → `lat`, `points[:,1]` → `lon`, `values` → `precip`. Does that make sense?

Comment: metpy.interpolate.interpolate_to_grid is useful as well.